# bundle local html files for android webview

Tags: android, webview, react-native

I am working with react native project and trying to add local html files to `webview`  in my project.
I tried this: `source= {require('file.html')}`
It works perfectly in debug version of ios and android, however after release, android shows white screen, ios is fine.
I also tried this: `source={{ uri: 'file:///android_asset/file.html' }}`
Didn't work either.

Is there any way to include local html files in webview for android version?

[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnUjE.png) of my code.

Comment: post snap of your code file. and code too

Comment: I added link to image in my post

Comment: can you try with single dot.

Answer (score 0):

You try this way for android

```
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/file.html");
```

Comment: I am working with react native, in react Webview doesn't have this method

Answer (score 0):

please try below code. Make sure your html file in same folder.

```
 <WebView
      style={{
        backgroundColor: '#123456',
        height: 100,
      }}
      source={require('./helloworld.html')}
      scalesPageToFit={true}
    />
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was trying to do. This is my code: <View style={styles.container}>
                <WebView

                    source={require('../journeyPlanner.html')}
                    automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
                    javaScriptEnabled={true}
                    domStorageEnabled={true}
                    decelerationRate="normal"
                    startInLoadingState={true}
                    scalesPageToFit={true}
                    ref={WEBVIEW_REF}
                    startLoadingState={true}
                />
            </View>

Comment: '../journeyPlanner.html  i can see double dots before slash

Comment: That is because I am trying to get html file from parent folder. My structure: Main folder (html file is here) > Component folder(webview with link to html file) Emulator of ios and Android could see this html, so I think path is right

Answer (score 0):

I just met the same problem recently, there is a discuss about this problem in Github https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/505, some guys supply a solution, it works for me.

for android release mode, you should put the html file in `android/app/src/main/assets` folder, and use WebView like this:

```
<WebView source={{uri: 'file:///android_asset/xxx.html'}}/>
```